# Why is my network stream downloading 0 bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp, stream

I'm currently working on a project that involves me taking a picture with my laptop camera on a given command. I'm using my webcam as a security camera right now due to the fact that I have not gotten the time to buy a real one yet so my laptop will have to do.
The project is structured like this:

I have my Server (this runs on my laptop) and I have my Client (which runs on my PC which will later be on my phone - but thats not relevant). I send a command to the server using my client (in this case it's "Webcam") and the server receives it, takes a picture using the webcam, gets the bytes and then sends the bytes over a network stream to the client.

However when I download the stream with my client, it downloads 0 bytes. To clarify, it does save the image in my folder but I can't open it because it's 0 bytes.

**Server**

```
        while (true)
        {
            if (nwStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                //Create a byte array (a buffer). This will hold the byte size that we recieve from the client in memory.
                byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

                //Now we need to read the bytes and store the bytes we read in a int, we do this by using our nwStream.Read function and pass it the correct parameters.
                //1. [Buffer] - an array of type byte, and we declared that above [buffer] <- This is what we are reading from.
                //2. [Offset] - Now we need to set the offset, where we want to start reading in the buffer. so since its an array we start at 0.
                //3. [Size] - The number of bytes we want to read from the NetworkStream.
                int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

                //Now we need to decode the message we recieved by using the Encoding.ASCII.GetString to get the string and passing the correct parameters.
                //1. [Bytes] - What we want to decode, this is where we give it a byte array 
                //2. [Index] - We need to give it the first index of the array that we want to decode so it knows where to start, we do this bya dding 0 since its an array.
                //3. [Count] - The number of bytes we want to decode and we created an int to hold that number above so let's pass it as a parameter.
                string dataRecieved = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                if (dataRecieved == "webcam")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting the webcam feature..");
                    CameraFeature();

                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static void CameraFeature()
    {
        VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

        foreach (FilterInfo Device in VideoCaptureDevices)
        {
            Devices.Add(Device.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Device: " + Device.Name);
        }

        FinalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[0].MonikerString);

        FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
        FinalVideo.Start();
    }

    private static void exitcamera()
    {
        FinalVideo.SignalToStop();
        // FinalVideo.WaitForStop();  << marking out that one solved it
        FinalVideo.NewFrame -= new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame); // as sugested
        FinalVideo = null;
    }

    static void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        //video.Save($"image{imgCount}.png");
        Console.WriteLine("Picture taken!");
        Connection(video);
        exitcamera();
        imgCount++;
    }


    public static void Connection(Bitmap tImage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting the transfer..");
        byte[] bStream = ImageToByte(tImage);

        try
        {
            nwStream.Write(bStream, 0, bStream.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Done..");

        }
        catch (SocketException e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: " + e1);
        }


    }

    static byte[] ImageToByte(Bitmap iImage)
    {
        MemoryStream mMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        iImage.Save(mMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return mMemoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
private static void SendCommand()  
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a command: ");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        //Convert out string message to a byteArray because we will send it as a buffer later.
        byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(userInput);

        //Write out to the console what we are sending.
        Console.WriteLine("Sending: " + userInput);

        //Use the networkstream to send the byteArray we just declared above, start at the offset of zero, and the size of the packet we are sending is the size of the messages length.
        nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);


        //RecieveBuffer();
        //Recieve the bytes that are coming from the other end (server) through the client and store them in an array.
        byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        //byte[] bitmap = GetYourImage();


        //read the bytes, starting from the offset 0, and the size is what ever the client has recieved.
        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

        //Decode the bytes we just recieved using the Encoding.ASCII.GetString function and give it the correct parameters
        //1. What it should decode
        //2. Starting to decode from what offset
        //3. How much do we want to decode?

        Bitmap bmp;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytesToRead))
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
            bmp.Save("Image.png");
        }
        //Console.WriteLine("Recieved: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `MemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` before sending stream to client. You may download 0 bytes, because stream at its end when you receive it.

Comment: Didnt seem to do anything

Comment: @TheHappyGuy have you tried to read stream on server before you send it? using Read method without any params.